# How to handle browser popup in Robot framework when monitor screen is close

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, popup, robotframework, screen

My script in Robot framework use **White library** to find a popup window and authenticates a user by entrering his username and password, then clicking on button to connect.

The script works well when monitor screen is open but **fails when monitor screen is closed** (i.e. windows session locked (ctrl+alt+del)). Script must be launched automatically any time by Jenkins. For this reason no screen is needed during test execution.

I have tried with **Autoit library** too without success, and I also tried to send credentials in URL like this "http://user:password@myserverurl.com". Which did not work because this popup appears in middle of the scenario of another application which authentication has already been made through another login page in the beginning of scenario.

Please send me your suggestions if there is **a way to simulate an opened monitor screen** or another library that I can use to *handle browser popup when monitor screen is close*.

Thank you in advance. My code :

```
WhiteLib.Attach Window    ${windowTitle}
WhiteLib.Press Keys    ${user}
WhiteLib.Press Special Key    TAB
WhiteLib.Press Keys    ${password}
WhiteLib.Press Special Key    TAB
WhiteLib.Press Special Key    RETURN
```

Comment: AFAIK, if the monitor is on or off, does not affect the access to ui elements but screen must not be locked - eg, user must be logged in and desktop has to be open.. This is essentially a windows feature and i dont think there are any workarounds for this ..

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rasjani. Can you please tell me if there is a special setting to do with JENKINS because it shows the same behaviour as if the windows session was locked. What do you mean by desktop has to be open ?  Wow can I close the monitor screen and leave the desktop open in Windows ?